# why does captcha fail on ie 9

Tags: playframework

On a browser by browser comparison.  Captcha in the yabe example worked great on Firefox 5.0 but was randomly generated junk on Internet Explorer 9

```
�PNG  IHDR�2��" IDATx��\}lE�*P+-RK��4DkD�j"*�F$�j$(�b� *��>BAĈ�"}�&5"��1�b�? ��ZE�h@c@-    X�G_�3ys�r���}���/���w�s���ٙ�}O ���s�ӀM���o7�^��<`-p0Ev'K�wo���" �5�z�E����PU��o�Y3
�-4�g`�r���{� `1p#����+�2��l�V��¸�n�?� l��(/IBʆ�7\� N����i���\�/�i ;��)lx�m�ܛ        \
```

etc etc etc

Is there a way to make captcha work as expected on IE9?

Comment: some [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) and your random junk seems to be sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this snippet:

```
Images.Captcha captcha = Images.captcha();
String code = captcha.getText("#E4EAFD");
Cache.set(id, code, "30mn");
renderBinary(captcha);
```

I think you should set the content type before rendering:

`response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("image/jpeg");`

Comment: I would also go in that direction, checking the content type has been set correctly.

Comment: It's part of some larger code.  Cache and response are either classes that need to be declared or a method that needs to be attached to a class like...
    Images.response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("image/jpeg");

Comment: `The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Cache cannot be resolved


In /app/controllers/Application.java (around line 42)

38:  }
39:  public static void captcha() {
40:   Images.Captcha captcha = Images.captcha();   //tutorial
41:   String code = captcha.getText("#E4EAFD");    //snippet
42:   Cache.set(id, code, "30mn");          //snippet
43:   response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("image/jpeg"); //I severely doubt this would work 
 44:   renderBinary(captcha);          //tutorial
45:   
 46:  }
47: }`

Answer (score 0):

On a similar topic, you may want to give the recaptcha module a try [link](http://www.playframework.org/modules/recaptcha).
The module integrates Google's captcha engine into you app. 2 minute integration garantied.

Captcha should have never made it to the core of Play - it doesn't go along the philosophy of the framework.

Comment: I'm sure to want to play with it when I start to build something.  Thanks for the head's up.